# zoom and show image from url in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

i load image from url with Image.network() in flutter app. but i want to show when user click on it and user can zoom and save in storage.

i use this package [OpenFile](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file)

`OpenFile.open("https://......com/image.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) library with Network Image provider :)